# How to retrieve the user account associated to a client certificate on SharePoint 2013

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication, ssl, certificate, custom-login-page

I’m searching for a while but I don’t find any answer to my problem. So now, i'm confused ... I hope to find an answer thanks to you.

On SharePoint 2013, I configured FBA with a custom login page.

I configured my SharePoint site in order to use SSL. To access the custom login page, it is necessary to provide a certificate which is associated to a user in the Active Directory

I would like to retrieve the Active Directory user associated to the certificate on my custom login page, but I don’t find how to do that...

In another project (ASP.NET Web service), just calling “base.User.Identity” did the trick

In my custom login page, I tried this:

- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name --> Nothing
- Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name --> Nothing
- WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent () Name --> NT AUTHORITY\IUSR
- base.User.Identity.Name --> Nothing

Do you have any idea how to get the AD user associated to the certificate?

Thank you in advance.

PS : Sorry for my poor English, I’m French speaking :-)